# Objective-C method 'client:didReceiveStatus:' provided by method 'client(_:didReceiveStatus:)' conflicts with optional requirement method

Tags: xcode, swift2, pubnub

Please find the below error for more information.

> Objective-C method 'client:didReceiveStatus:' provided by method
>   'client(*:didReceiveStatus:)' conflicts with optional requirement
>   method 'client(*:didReceiveStatus:)' in protocol
>   'PNObjectEventListener'

After `PubNub` pod installation when I implement the method in `swift 2.0` using Xcode 7.1 then this error occur. How I can resolve it?

Comment: Can you include some code or something? Is this being generated during `pod install`? Or within your application's code?

Comment: Also what version of PubNub are you using? That method was changed in later versions and is inconsistent with current documentation if you are copying and pasting from PubNub's sample code.